# JavaScript Object instantiation

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I'll see code like this:

```
var Obj = Obj || {};
```

What does this do? I have had success writing

```
array = array || [];
```

To instantiate an array if it hasn't already been instantiated, however I would like to know a bit more about the mechanics of this.

Comment: similar to c# `??` operator, but javascript does it without defining a new operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The technique tries to make use of something called **[short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**... but it's tricky in Javascript, and turns out to be quite dangerous if you try to make use of it for Object instantiation.

The theory behind short circuit evaluation is that an OR statement is only evaluated up to the first `true` value. So the second half of an OR statement is not evaluated if the first half is true. This applies to Javascript......

But, the peculiarities of Javascript, in particular how undeclared variables are handled, make this a technique that has to be used with great care to instantiate objects.

The following code creates an empty object except if Obj was previously declared in the same scope:

```
var Obj = Obj || {}; // Obj will now be {}, unless Obj was previously defined
                     //  in this scope function.... that's not very useful...
```

This is because after `var Obj`, `Obj` will be undefined unless it was declared in the same scope (**including** being declared as a parameter to the function, if any).... so `{}` will be evaluated. (**[Link to an explanation of var](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)** provided in the comments by T.J. Crowder).

The following code creates an empty object only if `Obj` has been **previously declared** and is now falsy:

```
Obj = Obj || {};     // Better make sure Obj has been previously declared.
```

If the above line is used when `Obj` has not been previously declared, there will be a runtime error, and the script will stop!

For example this Javascript will not evaluate at all:

```
(function() {
    Obj = Obj || "no Obj"; // error since Obj is undeclared JS cannot read from 
    alert(Obj);​            //   an undeclared variable. (declared variables CAN
})();                      //   be undefined.... for example "var Obj;" creates 
                           //   a declared but undefined variable. JS CAN try
                           //   and read a declared but undefined variable)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/87eH4/)**

But this Javascript will always set `Obj` to "no Obj"!

```
var Obj ="I'm here!";
(function() {
    var Obj = Obj || "no Obj"; // Obj becomes undefined after "var Obj"...
    alert(Obj);  // Output: "no Obj"
})();​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/a3rYt/)**

So using this type of short circuit evaluation in Javascript is dangerous, since you can usually only use it in the form

```
Obj = Obj || {};
```

Which will fail **precisely when you would most want it to work**... in the case where Obj is undeclared.

---

**Note:** I mention this in the comments of the penultimate example, but it's important to understand the 2 reasons that a variable can be undefined in Javascript.

1. A variable can be undefined because it was never declared.
2. A variable can be undefined because it was declared but has not had a value assigned to it.

A variable can be declared using the `var` keyword. Assigning a value to an undeclared variable creates the variable.

Trying to use an undefined variable that is also undeclared causes a **runtime error**. Using an undefined variable that has been declared is perfectly legal. This difference is what makes using `Obj = Obj || {};` so tricky, since there is no meaningful form of the previous statement if `Obj` is either undeclared OR it is a previously existing variable.

Comment: *"If Obj already exists, then evaluation of the above will stop at var Obj = Obj"* Wrong in the normal case. The fact that there's a `var Obj` means that by the time the `Obj || {}` part of that line evaluates (which happens well after the `var Obj` part is handled), `Obj` **will** be undefined, and so it doesn't matter if there's an `Obj` at a containing scope. The only time that statement would be true would be if there were *another* `var Obj` earlier *within the same scope* (function), which is very unusual.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - It is precisely for those unusual times that this is useful. The most common use of this would be to set a default value if the `Obj` argument is not passed into a function - Take a look at these 2 jsFiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/Ee7w3/ ---- http://jsfiddle.net/34rbS/

Comment: @Peter: The `var` in those fiddles has no purpose whatsoever, and obscures what's really happening. You're still modifying the argument. http://jsbin.com/emulo/2 (Not trying to turn this in to a jsbin vs. fiddle! ;-) )

Comment: @Peter: Right, but you've quoted the code `var Obj = Obj || {};` and then said that *"If `Obj` already exists, then evaluation of the above will stop at `var Obj = Obj`" My point is that that's not true except when someone has inadvertently written a redundant, and misleading, `var`. It's not useful (but is misleading) in terms of understanding what `||` does, because it's very easy to misread that statement as (cont'd)

Comment: @Peter: (Continuing) ..as *"If `Obj` already exists **in the containing scope**, then evaluation of the above will stop at `var Obj = Obj`". You'd read it that way because otherwise someone's written a completely unnecessary and misleading `var`, and why would you do that? The statement `var Obj = Obj || {};` doesn't make much sense, it should be `Obj = Obj || {};` or `var Obj = {};` but never `var Obj = Obj || {};` That's the point I, Darin, and CMS highlighted.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thanks for the explanation. The difference hand't really hit me until I saw CMS's example.

Comment: @Peter: *"After var Obj, Obj becomes undefined."* Mostly, yeah, if it's declaring a new symbol or shadowing one in the containing scope. If it's **re** declaring a variable or argument (as in your fiddles), the `var` part of it has no effect. All `var`s happen before the first line of the function runs, they declare things in the same namespace (actually an object) as arguments, and redundant `var` declarations are ignored. More here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html It's because JavaScript is **so** object-oriented it actually uses objects for scope.

Comment: @Peter: My pleasure! Isn't JS fun? ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Just when I think I've started to make progress in getting Javascript.... wow ;)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thanks. Looks like I accidentally clobbered that edit trying to figure out some other wording... added it back in.

Comment: @Peter: What would you recommend for the purpose of creating an object if it hasn't been instantiated? See https://gist.github.com/49acfe235c73b5807316

Comment: @Josh - I think you're actually okay there, since you've instantiated the `ret` object on line `1` with `ret={}` and you're not using `var` inside your function.... It's a slightly different case since `ret[num]` refers to a possibly defined value in an instantiated object. ---- What I would worry about is the `for in` w/o checking for `hasOwnProperty` or some other checks.... though it's hard to tell if that's necessary w/o knowing the context

Answer (score 3):

The mechanics are a bit unusual: Unlike most languages, JavaScript's `||` operator does *not* return `true` or `false`. Instead, it returns the first "truthy" value **or** the right-hand value. So for instance:

```
alert("a" || "b");              // alerts "a", because non-blank strings are "truthy"
alert(undefined || "b")         // alerts "b", because undefined is falsey
alert(undefined || false || 0); // alerts "0", because while all are falsy, 0 is rightmost
```

More in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).

As [Darin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755648/javascript-object-instantiation/3755665#3755665), your `var Obj = Obj || {};` is probably not a literal quote, more likely something like this:

```
function foo(param) {
    param = param || {};
}
```

...which means, "if the caller didn't give me something truthy for `param`, use an object."

Answer (score 2):

```
var Obj = Obj || {};
```

I think that the `var` here is not necessary. It should be:

```
Obj = Obj || {};
```

Where `Obj` is defined elsewhere. This will simply assign `Obj` to an empty object if it is null or leave as is of not. You might also leave the `var` keyword in which case it will  ensure that the object is declared even if it wasn't before this statement.

Same for the array: if it is null it will assign it to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding this syntax is that the result of a boolean or (or and) expression in JavaScript is the last-evaluated component. As has been pointed out by other commenters, JavaScript's shortcircuiting is being used along with this feature to conditionally set the value of `array` or `Obj`.

```
Obj = Obj || {};
```

This means Obj is set to the value of the expression `Obj || {}`. If Obj is "true", meaning it evaluates to true (for an object, this means it exists), the result of the expression is `Obj`, because the expression short-circuits. However, if `Obj` is "false" (non-existent), the second part of the expression must be evaluated. Therefore, in that case, the value of the expression is `{}`.